# How to handle new tab and click download in new browser tab - selenium webdriver with java

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a scenario, where a CTA will open a pdf document in a new tab, and I need to click on the down arrow (download button) in it (i am using selenium with java)[image]